# POA Clique Ethereum - Creation of Block

Tags: ethereum

In POA Clique Ethereum (Private Network)

Does it create a block even there is no transaction?
If yes, what's the benefit of creating always even there is no transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does create a block even when there is no transaction.

The idea behind creating blocks even when there is no transaction is to do with confirmations. By generating new blocks, older blocks (and their inner transactions) get more confirmations thus become even more reliable.

I hope that makes sense.